# Opencart API : Issue with session app_id (how to get api_id)

Tags: php, api, session, opencart, opencart2.3

I am working on Opencart API (opencart v2.3) and I follow this link for documentation ([Opencart](http://docs.opencart.com/system/users/api/) ) . But there is no data on opencart APIs and how to use it, So I follow steps from other websites and using that code I receive this message when call login api, **Success: API session successfully started!**

But whenever I use another API for add product in cart or view cart or add order, I receive permission issue. I debug code and found that it required session **app_id** and when I check, it store only **token**, not **app_id**

I use following code which I found by googling.
**common.php**

```
<?php
function do_curl_request($url, $params=array()) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'E:\practice\oc2.3\tmp\apicookie.txt');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'E:\practice\oc2.3\tmp\apicookie.txt');

  $params_string = '';
  if (is_array($params) && count($params)) {
    foreach($params as $key=>$value) {
      $params_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
    }
    rtrim($params_string, '&');

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($params));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params_string);
  }

  //execute post
  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  //close connection
  curl_close($ch);

  return $result;
}
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
require "common.php";

// set up params
$url = 'http://opencart2_3.local/index.php?route=api/restopencart/login';

$fields = array(
  'key' => 'FpafURRNAHgVcaUXZozahVdEOV7mtp1Q0ejvAMAIAfiZyVqIptqZ2uV9eQvT3PytlzELULH1vQwLKikFGBOm3yky1rTuFO6sEi0eBkH1y6WgpaNWIsB0ZMiRCCbGCBZZak2uR1CBg0TpOzcbevXWGStvoUsaKgl0B3OKRoHk6mRj7e6S63HJQzQksbbz0JfCuZsY9cvhY4ArQPzNf3XfrdgE3nTG5hYQCXaKPVqtS3R2Vqr4sazwjgXYajy7h6Dv',
);

$json = do_curl_request($url, $fields);
$data = json_decode($json);
if (isset($data->token)) {
  $token = $data->token;
}
var_dump($data);
```

**add_product.php**

```
<?php
require "common.php";

// set up params
$url = 'http://opencart2_3.local/index.php?route=api/restopencart/addproduct';
$fields = array(
  'product_id' => '32',
  'quantity' => '1',
  'option[226]' => '15'
);

$json = do_curl_request($url, $fields);
$data = json_decode($json);
var_dump($data);
```

**customer api**

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->language('api/customer');

    // Delete past customer in case there is an error
    unset($this->session->data['customer']);

    $json = array();

    if (!isset($this->session->data['api_id'])) {
        $json['error']['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
    } else {
        // Add keys for missing post vars
        $keys = array(
            'customer_id',
            'customer_group_id',
            'firstname',
            'lastname',
            'email',
            'telephone',
            'fax'
        );

        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            if (!isset($this->request->post[$key])) {
                $this->request->post[$key] = '';
            }
        }

        // Customer
        if ($this->request->post['customer_id']) {
            $this->load->model('account/customer');

            $customer_info = $this->model_account_customer->getCustomer($this->request->post['customer_id']);

            if (!$customer_info || !$this->customer->login($customer_info['email'], '', true)) {
                $json['error']['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_customer');
            }
        }

        if ((utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['firstname'])) < 1) || (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['firstname'])) > 32)) {
            $json['error']['firstname'] = $this->language->get('error_firstname');
        }

        if ((utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['lastname'])) < 1) || (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['lastname'])) > 32)) {
            $json['error']['lastname'] = $this->language->get('error_lastname');
        }

        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['email']) > 96) || (!filter_var($this->request->post['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) {
            $json['error']['email'] = $this->language->get('error_email');
        }

        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['telephone']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['telephone']) > 32)) {
            $json['error']['telephone'] = $this->language->get('error_telephone');
        }

        // Customer Group
        if (is_array($this->config->get('config_customer_group_display')) && in_array($this->request->post['customer_group_id'], $this->config->get('config_customer_group_display'))) {
            $customer_group_id = $this->request->post['customer_group_id'];
        } else {
            $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
        }

        // Custom field validation
        $this->load->model('account/custom_field');

        $custom_fields = $this->model_account_custom_field->getCustomFields($customer_group_id);

        foreach ($custom_fields as $custom_field) {
            if (($custom_field['location'] == 'account') && $custom_field['required'] && empty($this->request->post['custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id']])) {
                $json['error']['custom_field' . $custom_field['custom_field_id']] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_custom_field'), $custom_field['name']);
            } elseif (($custom_field['location'] == 'account') && ($custom_field['type'] == 'text') && !empty($custom_field['validation']) && !filter_var($this->request->post['custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id']], FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array('options' => array('regexp' => $custom_field['validation'])))) {
                $json['error']['custom_field' . $custom_field['custom_field_id']] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_custom_field'), $custom_field['name']);
            }
        }

        if (!$json) {
            $this->session->data['customer'] = array(
                'customer_id'       => $this->request->post['customer_id'],
                'customer_group_id' => $customer_group_id,
                'firstname'         => $this->request->post['firstname'],
                'lastname'          => $this->request->post['lastname'],
                'email'             => $this->request->post['email'],
                'telephone'         => $this->request->post['telephone'],
                'fax'               => $this->request->post['fax'],
                'custom_field'      => isset($this->request->post['custom_field']) ? $this->request->post['custom_field'] : array()
            );

            $json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
        }
    }

    if (isset($this->request->server['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $this->request->server['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
        $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
        $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
    }

    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the token right after your request URL will make it works.

Assume token returned by `api/login` is `KYMmXA4Bcj8nL9WD3nl0oalaJOL1KSKo`.

**add_product.php**

```
<?php
require "common.php";

// set up params
$url = 'http://opencart2_3.local/index.php?route=api/restopencart/addproduct&token=KYMmXA4Bcj8nL9WD3nl0oalaJOL1KSKo';
$fields = array(
  'product_id' => '32',
  'quantity' => '1',
  'option[226]' => '15'
);

$json = do_curl_request($url, $fields);
$data = json_decode($json);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: I already did this but I still get the error. I think somehow, somewhere the session gets refreshed or deleted or something. So you have any other ideas?

Comment: I'm getting the permission error, but I've already fixed this by copying how the new version of opencart handles the session.

Comment: @GellieAnn I am also having the same issue. Do you remember how you solved this issue?

Comment: @Aris, like what I said, I copied how the new version of opencart handles the session. It involves editing system/library/session.php and catalog/controller/startup/session.php. You just have to copy the code on the latest opencart. I've went to a lot of testing but I can't make the old version work, hence I decided to just use the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure server's IP address is added to the allowed IP addresses.

To check that, go to `System → Users → API` then edit the `Default` one.

Once there, click on `IP Address` tab and insert the server IP address.

To get the server IP address, you can use the following command line:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/ip
```